# How to configure IIS to deny client requests with empty client certificates?

Tags: ssl, iis, openssl, iis-8, tls1.2

I am trying to implement mutual authentication on an IIS Web Server which requires my clients to send a client certificate.

To test this, when i send make a request with OpenSSL without sending a client certificate, OpenSSL sends an empty certificate with length 0 which is surprisingly accepted by IIS which should not happen.

i read [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/101218/client-sent-certificate-with-zero-bytes-but-ssl-is-working-fine) that how the server deals with the empty certificate depends on the configuration. However, i cant seem to figure out exactly how to configure my IIS Server to deny client requests with empty client certificates?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!